# Django - compare values of keys in dictionaries in two different lists

Tags: django, dictionary, for-loop, django-templates, django-tagging

I have two lists of dictionaries that I have pulled from an XML file using elementtree. Each list of dictionaries contains dozens of keys/values but for simplicity sake let's say it's similar to the below:

```
list1 = [{'id': '100', 'first_name': 'john'}, {'id': '101', 'first_name': 'joe'}]
list2 = [{'id': '100', 'last_name': 'doe'}, {'id': '101', 'last_name': 'bloggs'}]
```

I'm using Django to build a table with the data and want to put the first names (from list1) and last names (from list2) on the same row of the table where there's a match in the 'id' values, but I can't figure out how to do this.

If I wanted to list them in python I would use:

```
for v in list1:
    print(v['id'])
    print(v['first_name'])
    for i in list2:
        if i['id'] == v['id']:
            print(i['last_name'])
```

But I can't figure out how to write this with django tags in the HTML template. Here's what I've tried (and variations thereof):

```
{% for v in list1 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{v.id}}</td>
        <td>{{v.first_name}}</td>
        {% for i in list2 %}
            {% if {{v.id}} == {{i.id}} %}
                <td>{{i.last_name}}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't do this in template. Prepare your data in the view and pass the processed data to the template.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could do the logic in the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `{{}}` within `{%%}`

Django's template engine really doesn't like that.

Write it like this:

```
        {% for i in list2 %}
            {% if v.id == i.id %}
                <td>{{i.last_name}}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

> Sidenote:
>
> You are comparing ID's. Is it a related object? Is it the same model?